# Simple database for storing time series data of different datatypes

Tags: .net, database, windows, time-series

I'm looking for a simple database to use in my .NET application to log values from different sources, and retrieve values back later filtered by a date time range.

The values that should be stored can be as simple as

```
{
    "timestamp": "2015-05-13 16:40:23",
    "temperature": 22.3
}
```

though another source could have a more complex value, such as a value with several members:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2015-05-13 16:40:23",
    "velocity": {
        "x": 1.3,
        "y": 1.01,
        "z": 0.04
    }
}
```

or alternatively a value being an array:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2015-05-13 16:40:23",
    "velocity": [1.3, 1.01, 0.04]
    }
}
```

Each data source will not supply samples more often than twice a second, and there will not be many of them "live" at any given time (maybe 10 that are active and supplying data, while another 20 are idle. Though which are active and which are idle changes), so performance is not really that important. The most important part is to simply add new "tables" to a database if new data sources with different value structures are added to the system.

I am most familiar with using SQL, but I figured there may be something simpler for my use-case where there are no relationships, just keys (the timestamp) and values. I tried googling, and mostly found solutions for Linux-systems.

Comment: What *is* your use case? How much data are you going to log and how frequently? How often are you going to read it and what will you do with the data?  Key/value stores are the worst possible idea for range queries. Unless you want to handle very large loads, a SQL database with indexes on the timestamp columns is probably the simplest solution as indexes can serve range queries as easily as single item queries

Comment: I'm not aware of any non-relational time-series databases built for Windows. But you can run a database in a Linux virtual machine on the side. Is this an option?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use mongoDB for that, and it has .net driver supports
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/?jmp=docs